# Uploading picture via mobile camera without requiring storage permission

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to upload a picture in a web app using the phone camera. and I'm  using the `input` type file tag like so:

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" onchange="upload(this)" accept="image/*" capture/>
```

and in my javascript code, I'm using a simple XHR object to send the picture to the server as a formdata.

But I found out in order to send the picture straight via phone camera the browser app (Firefox, Chrome... ) must have **storage permission**.

Is there any other way I can do this without the storage permission?

Comment: `onchage="upload(this) accept="image/*"` - there's at least **two** things wrong with this

Comment: you know that you **must have storage permission**  - so you're asking for a hack/workaround/secret everyone else but you knows?

Comment: If a web page snaps a picture to be uploaded directly & not saved locally (apart from temp location), one could wonder if it's possible to do so without requiring storage permission. I thought that was an interesting question & fixed the obvious typo -- apologies if that typo *was* the issue, feel free to edit it back in...

Comment: Are you expecting camera at computer to take photographs of user without user permission? And send the photographs to your application?

Comment: no iam no saying i want to use phone camera without user permission. obviously when the user clicks on the upload button the browser will ask file source from the user (storage, camera, ...) when getting the file from storage there's no problem but when I choice camera app my XHR request fails @HuguesM.

Comment: I did not reword anything in the question, that was just formatting/typos/style, but I did reword the title a bit to match the body. Please edit again to add these new details, please include more details about how the XHR fails, and rephrase title as you like. Also please specify if that's Android or iOS or...